# Can I say "take effort"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

It seems to me “take efforts”, “take a great effort” “take the effort to do something”, all three are ok. But I wonder whether you say “take effort” as a set phrase to mean something abstractly, for example:

People always take effort to be a better person, though they may be ignorant of what it means to become a better person.

Comment: No. One ***takes** umbrage, takes pains, takes care,* and _takes one's time,_ but one ***makes** an effort, makes an attempt,* or _makes certain_. Different metaphors, see.

Comment: @JohnLawler that comment as an answer would win my upvote.

Comment: While there are mistakes in the question, the more i think of the answer, the more i like it.

Answer (score 13):

Something can **take effort** to accomplish. No one would doubt that it took Einstein some great effort to develop his theory of relativity, even though it is an abstraction of a sort. Something can also take courage, take time, take honesty, take patience, take kindness, etc. In this case, *taking* means meeting a requirement.

However, the person actually expending this effort is **making the effort**. One can *make an/the effort* to be a better person, though this **takes** courage, honesty, etc. You can also **make time** to do things. [**Make**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make) is a complicated verb, one meaning meaning of which is to cause (something) to exist or come about; bring about. One *makes* changes.

edited to add OP's example:

> **It**  **takes effort** to become a better person.

but

> **People**  **make an effort** to be a better person...

Comment: +1, and I think the most natural phrasing for the example sentence is "make an effort", rather than "make the effort".

Comment: I think you should address the sample sentence the asker offers -- which is mistaken.

Comment: In a nutshell: _Things take effort -- effort that we make._ Damn those things!

Answer (score 0):

You can also say that you put effort into something.

You need to put effort into completing your master's degree.

Comment: What about the question _Can I say "take effort"?_